# swagger autorest client usage

Tags: .net, swagger, partial, autorest

i have solution where i have multiple webapi projects they communicate over rest so i want to use autorest and swagger to generate clients, autorest works fine and create client and object classes, but actually i don't want to use them as i already have same objects in shared project and i can do this by not addind Models into autorest generated client project, but then i need make changes in apiclient after every time i regenerage client, maybe there is way to use that generated model classes are "partial" as they have same name and namespace so compiler will somehow combine them and use like one?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a partial class for your client.

For example you have an auto-generated client called ServiceClient.cs, you just create a ServiceClient.Partial.cs where you can put your own custom logic.

```
namespace Example.APIClients.Service
{
    public partial class ServiceClient
    {
        partial void CustomInitialize()
        {
            SetRetryPolicy(null);
        }

        // Constructor if you need it
        public ServiceClient(...)
        {
            // some code
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use your own logic and the auto-generated clients depending on what you need.